# JS: Group by 2 keys

Tags: javascript, lodash, reduce

I have like to group an array of objects.

```
var _ = require('lodash')

const objects = [
  { a: 'test1', b: 'sample', c: 'ten' },
  { a: 'test2', b: 'sample', c: 'ten' },
  { a: 'test3', b: 'sampleone', c: 'ten' },
  { a: 'test4', b: 'sample', c: 'tentwo' },
]

//using lodash, groupBy b and c and concat 'a' values
const grouped = _(objects)
  .groupBy('b', 'c')
  .map((value, key) => ({
    b: key,
    c: value[0].c,
    a: _.map(value, 'a').join('|'),
  }))
  .value()

console.log(grouped)
```

The output from above is:

```
[
  { b: 'sample', c: 'ten', a: 'test1|test2|test4' },
  { b: 'sampleone', c: 'ten', a: 'test3' }
]
```

But I have like the output to be below, only group by b is 'sample' and c is 'ten'

```
[
  { b: 'sample', c: 'ten', a: 'test1|test2' },
  { b: 'sampleone', c: 'ten', a: 'test3' },
  { b: 'sample', c: 'tentwo', a: 'test4' }
]
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To group by multiple keys you will to need do something like

```
.groupBy(({b,c}) => `${b}|${c}`)
```

i.e joining the individual keys and creating a new composite key (also will have create it in such a way that it becomes unique)

now the grouped object will look like this before the `map` call

```js
{
  sampleone|ten: [{
  a: "test3",
  b: "sampleone",
  c: "ten"
}],
  sample|ten: [{
  a: "test1",
  b: "sample",
  c: "ten"
}, {
  a: "test2",
  b: "sample",
  c: "ten"
}],
  sample|tentwo: [{
  a: "test4",
  b: "sample",
  c: "tentwo"
}]
}
```

```js
const objects = [
  { a: 'test1', b: 'sample', c: 'ten' },
  { a: 'test2', b: 'sample', c: 'ten' },
  { a: 'test3', b: 'sampleone', c: 'ten' },
  { a: 'test4', b: 'sample', c: 'tentwo' },
]


const grouped = _(objects)
  .groupBy(({b,c}) => `${b}|${c}`)
  .map((value, key) => ({
    b: value[0].b,
    c: value[0].c,
    a: _.map(value, 'a').join('|'),
  }))
  .value()

console.log(grouped)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.21/lodash.min.js"></script>
```